# Ffmpeg x11grab exported video 16:9 is distorded

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

using fluent ffmepg with **ffmpeg version 3.4.4.**

Capturing screen using x11grab with that setup :

```
videoCommand
.addInput(display)
.addInputOptions('-y', '-f' , 'x11grab' , '-draw_mouse', '0')
.aspect('16:9')
.withSize('768x432')
.withFpsInput(60)
.withFpsOutput(60)
.output(base_path+'/'+process.argv[3]+'.mp4')
```

It works great except that video image is distorded, like in the second picture below.

1 - image that x11 is displaying
[image]

2 - image in the resulting video
[image]

3- Properties of the exported video 
[image]

Tried to use .keepDAR() option for ffmpeg but i got a 4:3 video.

This is ffmpeg log : i don't know from where that 640*480 is coming

[image]

Comment: Does your screen have the same aspect ratio? Try with `autopad()`.

Comment: @aergistal yes 16:9 > 2560x1440 and 1920x1080

Comment: Share full ffmpeg log.

Comment: @Gyan Question edited with log

Comment: @direxit add `-video_size 1920x1080`  to `addInputOptions` before `-f x11grab`. See [the wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop).

Comment: @aergistal thanks, found this :  '-s' , '768x432' as input option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as an input option : ie : **'-s' , '768x432'**

```
.addInputOptions('-y', '-f' , 'x11grab' , '-draw_mouse', '0' , '-s' , '768x432')
```

Comment: x11grab size option is `-video_size`, not `-s`. See [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#Options-21).

Comment: @llogan yes that was already set with in initial code :

.withSize('768x432')
Aliases: videoSize(), withSize().

Comment: @llogan is right, `withSize` sets the output frame size. It works because `-s` is mapped to `-video_size` when used for an input format but I think it was deprecated.

Comment: I don't know if it really matters with `-video_size` vs `-s`: I never looked into. However, it can matter with `-framerate` vs `-r`, and anyway it is good practice to use the documented options, so that is why I mention it.

Comment: There is différences in the way params  are called / passed with « fluent ffmpeg «